# Make a vertical spacing plot

Tags: matlab, data-analysis

I need to make a B-scan data from a chunk of A-scan data. The A-scan data that I received are arranged in such a way that the row resembles the amplitude of the each point of the A-scan data and the column represents each A-scan data gathered. 
This is how my data looks like:

```
4855    4641    4891    4791    4812    4812
4827    4766    4862    4745    4767    4785
6676    5075    6903    6879    6697    6084
7340    6829    7678    7753    7263    6726
6176    6237    6708    6737    6316    5943
12014   10467   10915   10914   10124   10642
8251    7538    7641    7619    7269    7658
6522    6105    6132    6136    5921    6227
5519    5287    5330    5376    5255    5237
4904    4784    4835    4855    4794    4758
4553    4527    4472    4592    4469    4455
4298    4323    4291    4293    4221    4238
4167    3957    4089    3991    3938    3907
3789    3721    3777    3777    3643    3596
3736    4615    3639    2814    3638    2782
4413    5286    4248    3998    4370    4199
5994    6896    6134    5548    6102    6161
8506    9020    7841    8060    8663    8941
12347   12302   10639   11151   12533   12478
18859   18175   15035   15938   18358   18160
27106   26261   22613   24069   27015   27114
32767   32601   32767   32767   32767   32767
32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767
32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767
32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767
32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767
32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767
26416   26459   32767   32767   26308   26945
6523    6900    13327   16665   6616    6477
-14233  -14011  -8554   -5649   -13956  -13858
-28128  -26784  -26157  -24055  -27875  -28374
-28775  -27905  -30348  -26285  -28918  -29066
-20635  -19776  -21144  -21548  -22107  -22759
-16915  -15742  -15908  -17398  -19600  -20143
```

This is just the sample of the data. It is in .txt format.

[A-scan data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQipS.png)
[B-scan data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PpJ6.png)

The problem I am facing is to plot this data into a b-scan data. Matlab would be great (Though other methods would be great too). Please share your way of plotting this B-scan data.

Comment: The question is very unclear. What are A and B scans? What do you want to do, exactly?

Comment: I attached an image of what A and B scans data are. I need to plot a B-scan data from a A-scan data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Scilab

On Scilab you can use the `read` function. It reads formatted texted files, and you need to know at least the number of columns. To add vertical spacing, you should add a constant value `i*d` for each whole column, where `i` is the column number.

I put the example you gave in a text file so I could read it, than I plotted it.

```
//read(): first argument is file path 
//        (or file name, if you change current directory)
//        second argument is number of lines (-1 if unknown)
//        third argument is the number of columns
B = read("file.txt",-1,6);

d  = 1000; //vertical spacing
Bs = B;    //copy of the original data

for i = 1 : size(Bs,'c')
    //loop adding constant to each column
    Bs(:,i) = Bs(:,i) + (i-1) * d;
end

//simply plot the matrix
plot2d(Bs);
```

The result in Scilab is:
[image: Scilab result]

---

### MATLAB

In MATLAB, you can use the `importdata` function, which also reads formatted text files, but the minimum necessary is the file name. You should also add the vertical spacing manually.

```
%call importdata() after changing current directory
B = importdata("file.txt");

d  = 1000; %vertical spacing
Bs = B;    %copy of the original data

for i = 1 : size(Bs,2)
    %loop adding constant to each column
    Bs(:,i) = Bs(:,i) + (i-1) * d;
end    

%plot the modified matrix
plot(Bs);
```

The result in MATLAB is:
[image: MATLAB result]

Comment: Thanks!, can you make a plot like the b-scan image?

Comment: @hphys And what is the difference between these plots and the B-scan image?

Comment: In B-scan, the A-scan data stacks up onto each A-scan creating an image like you see in the image I shared above. while this one just doesn't stack.

Comment: @hphys You mean there is a vertical space between the lines. Is that it? I thought the data itself had that spacement, and not that it should be done manually. If you do that, the vertical axis will not represent the absolute value for the data, it will be ``y' = y + d``, where ``y`` is the original value and ``d`` is the spacement. Is that ok? Is that what you need?

Comment: yeah, that is what I need. do you know how I could do that and could you show me how to do it? Thanks! I appreciate your help.

Comment: @hphys As commented in your original question, you should clarify it. Perhaps it needs another update to make it more clear. I will also edit my answer.

Comment: @hphys Let me know if the answer is what you want by accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 %ploting columnspace
 figure(1)
 plot3([0 columnspaceA(1,1)],[0 columnspaceA(2,1)],[0 
 columnspaceA(3,1)],'y- ^', 'LineWidth',3) 
  

 hold on
 plot3([0 columnspaceA(1,2)],[0 columnspaceA(2,2)],[0 
 columnspaceA(3,2)],'y-^', 'LineWidth',3) 
   
 %ploting leftynullspace
 plot3([0 leftnullspace(1,1)],[0 leftnullspace(2,1)],[0 
 leftnullspace(3,1)],'g','linew',3)
        
     
h=fmesh(@(s,t)columnspaceA(1,1)*s+columnspaceA(1,2)*t,@(s,t)columnspaceA(2,1)*s+columnspaceA(2,2)*t,@(s,t)columnspaceA(3,1)*s+columnspaceA(3,2)*t,[-1 1]);


figure(2)
%ploting nullspace
hold on
 plot3([0 nullspace(1,1)],[0 nullspace(2,1)],[0 nullspace(3,1)],'g-^','LineWidth',3) 
        

% %ploting rowspace
 plot3([0 rowspaceA(1,1)],[0 rowspaceA(2,1)],[0 rowspaceA(3,1)],'r-^','LineWidth',3) 
       

 hold on
 plot3([0 rowspaceA(1,2)],[0 rowspaceA(2,2)],[0 rowspaceA(3,2)],'r-^','LineWidth',3) 
       
 h1 = fmesh(@(s,t)rowspaceA(1,1)*s+rowspaceA(1,2)*t,@(s,t)rowspaceA(2,1)*s+rowspaceA(2,2)*t,@(s,t)rowspaceA(3,1)*s+rowspaceA(3,2)*t,[-1 1]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).